How to apply a Hadamard gate to the first qubit and then measure that first qubit in the computational basis
I am reading lecture notes from Ronald de Wolf on quantum computing and trying to solve exercise 7 from chapter 1. I am having a bit of trouble understanding exactly what I need to do and how to do it. The description goes as this:
Suppose we have the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle  |\phi\rangle   + |1\rangle  |\psi\rangle  )$, where $|\phi\rangle  $ and $|\psi\rangle  $ are unknown normalized quantum states with the same number of qubits. Suppose we apply a Hadamard gate to the first qubit and then measure that first qubit in the computational basis. Give the probability of measurement outcome 1, as a function of the states $|\phi\rangle  $ and $|\psi\rangle  $.
Here is my process of thought. The states of $|\phi\rangle  $ and $|\psi\rangle  $ are of arbitrary size, however have the same number of qubits. Let's say that the two states consists of $n$ qubits. Then, to apply the hadamard gate to only the first qubit I would do $H\otimes I^{\otimes n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle  |\phi\rangle   + |1\rangle  |\psi\rangle  )$ from my understanding. Since the first part is $|0\rangle  |\phi\rangle  $ I would assume that applying the hadamard gate to the first qubit would result in essentially something like $\frac{1}{2} \phi_1 + \frac{1}{2}\phi_2$, as the first two amplitudes of the quantum state.
Then I would expect that when performing the measurement we create $P_1$ as a projector of the 1 state. That is $P_1=|1\rangle  \langle1|$. Then we calculate the probability. But I don't know fully how to formally define this or if I am on the right track. Note, I am taking a course on quantum computing, but this is not any exercise or homework from the course itself, this is something I am doing myself to try to get a better understanding of the concepts and the field in general. I would appreciate any help :)

You're definitely on the right tracks! Here's some hints to help you a bit.
You have to remember that in quantum computing, everything is linear. In particular, applying a gate to a superposition is the same as applying the gate individually to each of the terms.
Suppose the state was $|0,\phi\rangle$. As a recall, this is equal to $|0\rangle\otimes|\phi\rangle$. You're correct that applying an $H$ gate on the first qubit means applying $H\otimes I_{2^{n-1}}$ on the whole state. Because of the distributivity of tensor product, we have:
$$\left(H\otimes I_{2^{n-1}}\right)(|0\rangle\otimes|\phi\rangle)=H|0\rangle\otimes I_{2^{n-1}}|\phi\rangle=\frac{|0\rangle+|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\otimes|\phi\rangle\,.$$
Similarly, we have:
$$\left(H\otimes I_{2^{n-1}}\right)(|1\rangle\otimes|\psi\rangle)=H|1\rangle\otimes I_{2^{n-1}}|\psi\rangle=\frac{|0\rangle-|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\otimes|\psi\rangle\,.$$
By linearity, we thus have:
$$\left(H\otimes I_{2^{n-1}}\right)(|0\rangle\otimes|\phi\rangle+|1\rangle\otimes|\psi\rangle)=\frac{|0\rangle+|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\otimes|\phi\rangle+\frac{|0\rangle-|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\otimes|\psi\rangle\,.$$
In order to get the probability you seek, you're also correct that you have to apply a projector on this state. But the $P_1$ you wrote acts on a single qubit, just like the $H$ gate before. How could you make it act on the whole system instead?
After that, you just have to compute the squared norm of the state you get in order to get your result. Can you take it from here?

So as soon as a quantum state is in some superposition we have to apply the operation to each of the terms describing the state? Is this correctly understood?

@ThobiasLarsen Yes, the states are vectors, and the operations you apply on them are matrices, so by linearity it's equivalent to apply the matrix to each term separately and then do the sum!

@ThobiasLarsen Essentially, for a matrix $M$, two vectors $v$ and $w$ and two complex numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we have $M(\alpha v+\beta w)=\alpha MV+\beta Mw$. In your case, $M$ is the quantum gate and $v$ and $w$ are the quantum states in the superposition. That's why we apply it on both of them. This is also where the "speed" of quantum computing kicks in: it's just like we applied our gate in parallel to all elements in the superposition

You can compute the state just before measurement:
$$
H \otimes I^{\otimes (n-1)} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \left|0\right\rangle\left|\phi\right\rangle + \left|1\right\rangle\left|\psi\right\rangle \right) \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \left|+\right\rangle\left|\phi\right\rangle + \left|-\right\rangle\left|\psi\right\rangle \right)
$$
With $\left|\pm\right\rangle$ = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \left|0\right\rangle \pm \left|1\right\rangle\right )$, you get:
$$
|A\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \left|+\right\rangle\left|\phi\right\rangle + \left|-\right\rangle\left|\psi\right\rangle \right) = \frac{\left|0\right\rangle (\left|\phi\right\rangle + \left|\psi\right\rangle)}{2} + \frac{\left|1\right\rangle (\left|\phi\right\rangle - \left|\psi\right\rangle)}{2}
$$
Considering $P_0 = |0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I^{\otimes (n-1)}$ and $P_1 = |1\rangle\langle1|\otimes I^{\otimes (n-1)}$ the projectors linked with measurement outcome 1 and -1 of the observable $M= P_0 - P_1 = Z\otimes I^{\otimes (n-1)}$, the two possible measurement outcomes for $M$ are:
$$\frac{P_0|A\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle A|P_0|A\rangle}} = \frac{|0\rangle (\left|\phi\right\rangle + \left|\psi\right\rangle)}{2\sqrt{\frac{1+\langle\phi|\psi\rangle}{2}}}$$
with probability:
$$\langle A|P_0|A\rangle = \frac{(\langle\phi|+\langle\psi|)\langle0|\,|0\rangle\langle0|\,|0\rangle(|\phi\rangle + |\psi\rangle)}{4} = \frac{\langle\phi|\phi\rangle + \langle\psi|\psi\rangle + 2 \langle\phi|\psi\rangle}{4} = \frac{1 + \langle\phi|\psi\rangle}{2}
$$
Or for measurement outcome -1:
$$\frac{P_1|A\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle A|P_1|A\rangle}} = \frac{|1\rangle (\left|\phi\right\rangle - \left|\psi\right\rangle)}{2\sqrt{\frac{1-\langle\phi|\psi\rangle}{2}}}$$
with probability:
$$\langle A|P_1|A\rangle = \frac{(\langle\phi|-\langle\psi|)\langle1|\,|1\rangle\langle1|\,|1\rangle(|\phi\rangle - |\psi\rangle)}{4} = \frac{\langle\phi|\phi\rangle + \langle\psi|\psi\rangle - 2 \langle\phi|\psi\rangle}{4} = \frac{1 - \langle\phi|\psi\rangle}{2}
$$
This is not surprising: if $|\psi\rangle = \pm|\phi\rangle$, then the initial state was $|\pm\rangle|\phi\rangle$ which then becomes $|0\rangle|\phi\rangle$ or $|1\rangle|\phi\rangle$.
On the contrary, the measurement outcome can only be 50/50 if and only if $|\phi\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle$ are orthogonal (e.g. $|\phi\rangle = |0\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle = |1\rangle$).

Is there any specific reason or benefit of using an observable here instead of just calculating individually for the projection? Or rather, you showed the observable $M=P_0-P_1$, but it doesn't seem like you are using it in the rest of the answer? I will re-read the whole chapter of the book tonight and hope it makes more sense now that I have worked a bit more with it anyways.

How come that $\langle A|P_0|A\rangle=\frac{(\langle\phi|+\langle\psi|)\langle 0| |0\rangle \langle 0| |0\rangle (|\phi\rangle+|\psi\rangle)}{4}$? I understand the bra and ket parts, but from this it looks like $P_0=\langle 0| |0\rangle \langle 0||0\rangle$, which, from my intuition does not correspond with the conclusion you wrote where $P_0=|0\rangle\langle 0|\otimes I^{\otimes (n-1)}$

A quantum measurement is always linked to an observable. In this case, it is easy to compute the projection without using this notion, but it is something to keep in mind in more involved cases with potentially a large number of variable. This observable is also the operator whose eigenvalue corresponds to the measurement outcome the question talk about, so writing it seemed benefical to me.

The leftmost $\langle 0 |$ and rightmost $|0\rangle$ come from the first qubit of $\langle A|$ and $|A\rangle$. $P_0$ is indeed $|0\rangle\langle 0| \otimes I^{\otimes (n-1)}$, I just omitted the $I$ part, since quantities like $\langle a | I^{\otimes (n-1)} | b \rangle$ are always equal to $\langle a | b \rangle$.

Shouldn't the post measured states be $$\frac{P_0|A\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle A|P_0|A\rangle}} = \frac{|0\rangle (\left|\phi\right\rangle + \left|\psi\right\rangle)}{2\sqrt{\frac{1 + \langle\phi|\psi\rangle}{2}}}$$? It would only be $$\frac{P_0|A\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle A|P_0|A\rangle}} = \frac{|0\rangle (\left|\phi\right\rangle + \left|\psi\right\rangle)}{\sqrt{2}}$$ if $$\langle A|P_0|A\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
